# cfset or cffunction?

Tags: coldfusion

In coldfusion, in the hidden values of a form I get two values:

```
            <input type="hidden" name="EST_VAL" value="#EST_VAL#" />
            <input type="hidden" name="DOWN_PMT" value="#DOWN_PMT#" />
```

I need to find the value of EST_VAL subtracted from DOWN_PMT and assign it to this value:

```
            <input type="hidden" name="LOAN_VAL" value="#LOAN_VAL#" />
```

I know how to do this in PHP, but I'm not sure if I should use a cfset, or cffunction in coldfusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFSET should be all you need for this. Without seeing the other code in this file/script, a simple approach/solution would entail the following:

```
<cfset LOAN_VAL = EST_VAL - DOWN_PMT />
```

That would then output the value of the LOAN_VAL variable in the hidden field tag you note in your original post.

Comment: Glad it worked. But, I'll readily admit that Mark's response is cleaner and nicer if you only need that var in the one hidden field :)!

Answer (score 7):

you can do this inline with pound signs like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="LOAN_VAL" value="#EST_VAL-DOWN_PMT#"/>
```